# Flask questions about BaseConverter and __init.py__

Tags: flask

I am trying to use a custom Baseconverter to ensure that my urls are "clean". I finally got it to work as follows:

My `init.py` is:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
from flask.ext.openid import OpenID
from config import basedir
from slugify import slugify
app = Flask(__name__)
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter
class MyStringConverter(BaseConverter):
    def to_python(self, value):
        return value
    def to_url(self, values):
        return slugify(values)
app.url_map.converters['mystring'] = MyStringConverter
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)
lm.login_view = 'login'
oid = OpenID(app, os.path.join(basedir, 'tmp'))

from app import views, models
```

But if I define the `MyStringConverter` class and add `app.url_map.converters['mystring'] = MyStringConverter` at the end of the file instead, I got a `LookupError: the converter 'mystring' does not exist` error. Why is this?

Is this the correct way to clean up my urls? I'm not sure if I need to do anything to the `to_python()` method or if I am going about this the right way.

Comment: If you are looking up records in a database, you'll probably want to create the slug when you insert the record rather than using a custom converter every time you need to build a URL. With the converter you'll have a hard time knowing if `'this-string'` is really `'this string'`, `'This string'`, or `'THIS STRING'`.

Comment: I don't see why that is. A sample view is `@app.route('/search_results/<mystring:query>')
def search_results(query): return render_template("results.html", query=query)` Here I still have access to the exact query.

Comment: Is there ever a time when you need the version that was passed to `slugify`?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. You mean that inside `search_results()` the query input will be the slugified version. I was under then impression that the slugified version would get routed, but the view function will still get the original, which does'nt appear to be the case. That means I have to either store the slugified versions as you suggested, or do some sort of un-slugify in my view functions? I guess a third option would be to pass **both** the the slugified and original strings, but I don't think there is a way to hide the original in the url but still access it in the view function?

Comment: You could try to reverse the slug, but there's no one to reliably handle things like case or white space and punctuation. And if you end up passing both in the URL, there's no point in using the slug at all.